# Jenkins - cannot Install Plugins/Upgrades

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to learn how to use Jenkins.

When it needs to install the plugins, most of installation's plugins are getting a failure result.

I want Jenkins to download plugins automatically unattended.

> Jenkins ver. 2.140

What do I need to do?

Thanks :)

There is an example of error message:

```
Token Macro 
 Failure -
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected 649686 but only got 2432
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1153)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/token-macro/2.5/token-macro.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp-chi.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/token-macro/2.5/token-macro.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1178)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1715)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1978)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and another error message

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\workflow-cps\WEB-INF\lib\diff4j-1.2.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.


    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:316)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:388)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:407)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:387)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:407)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:387)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:407)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:387)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:365)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\workflow-cps'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:370)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:625)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:182)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:860)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:825)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1993)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1997)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Does the server hosting jenkins has access to the internet? Although annoying to install manually, there is at least [this repository](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/) containing most of the hpis, which avoid you the step of manual compilation through `mvn hpi:hpi`

Comment: It does not work, it still shows the message that it can not download the plugins

Comment: Does the issue still occur if you upgrade to the latest version of Jenkins?

Comment: What does "it" refers to, as I asked several questions, could you be more explicit?

Comment: please use jdk version 11